# batch: escaping special characters like “ and ” in a variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping, batch-processing

This script (in addition to searching for duplicate files) renames files to not include special characters (within a single folder). I am still having trouble when the filename has characters like `“` and `”`. I tried adding that within the `delayedexpansion` and also outside it without success.

```
@echo off
echo "%~1" | find /i "system volume information" >nul && exit /b
echo "%~1" | find /i "s-1-5-21-3" >nul && exit /b
echo "%~1" | find /i "recycle" >nul && exit /b
cd /d %1 2>nul
if /i not "%~1"=="%cd%" echo cannot access %~n1 && exit /b

for %%v in (*) do set "original=%%~nxv" & call :validate
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a-d') do set "compare=%cd%\%%v" & call :detection
exit /b

:validate
:: add handling of “ and ”
set "newtitle=%original:!=%"
set "newtitle=%newtitle:”=%"
set "newtitle=%newtitle:&=and%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "newtitle=!newtitle:%%= percent!"
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
if not "%original%"=="%newtitle%" ren "%original%" "%newtitle%" && echo validated %newtitle%
goto next

:detection
:: this extrapolates %string% from beginning of filename
call d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd "%compare%" data
set count=0
for %%v in ("%string%*") do set /a "count+=1"
for %%v in ("%string%*") do if not "%count%"=="1" echo "%%v"
:next
```

Comment: A file name cannot have characters like **“** and **”**

Comment: well youtube downloader does successfully save those filenames to my NTFS drive. and now that I tried I can too. I think it's just the straight `"` that are illegal.

Comment: @Compo Why do you think so? I just put your exact sentence into a file name. But batch is not the ideal environment to deal with these chars. I suggest using PowerShell.

Comment: The typographical quotation marks are not special to `cmd`, so you do not need to escape them. However, I guess these are Unicode-encoded characters, which `cmd` cannot handle properly; you could try playing around with different codepages ([`chcp`](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)), but I fear you might not have success. I believe handling these files not by `cmd` (so switching to PowerShell, for instance) is the only reliable way...

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell one liner should recursivley find files (from current folder ) with typographic quotes and remove them.

```
$Search = '“|”';gci -r -file |where Name -Match $Search|Ren -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Search} -Confirm
```

Simply paste into a PowerShell console and let it run. 
The `-Confirm` parameter will let you ask for every rename

Sample output:

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item: A:\A file name cannot have characters like “ and ” 
 Destination: A:\A file name cannot have characters like  and ".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

---

Normally I'd embed the powershell code like this:

```
powershell -NoP -Command "$Search = '“|”';gci -r -file |where Name -Match $Search|Ren -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Search}"
```

But keep in mind that powershell normally uses UTF16 like windows itself internally, so here code page limits apply.
I couldn't paste this into my chcp 850 based console - the typographic quotes were exchanged to normal ones.

Comment: about moving over to powershell; can I do it incrementally by just running a line of powershell from within a regular batch script or do I have to rewrite the entire thing? what if a script calls for an other script, can I call powershell scripts from regular batch scripts and vice versa?

Comment: I'll embed the above line in a batch. In general mixing commands requires quoting/escaping to not let the one shell interpret commands meant for the other one.

Comment: can you elaborate on the UTF/CHCP and page limits?

Comment: Code pages was/is a crippled way to stay with 8bit chars assigning the upper (non ASCII) half to region specific chars. Just some links [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [Windows_code_page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page), [Code_page_850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) and [Code_page_437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Comment: I tested the embedded code in command prompt and got error `'"';gci -r -file |where Name -Match $Search|Ren -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Search}"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Did you paste from clipboard into a cmd window or execute from a file? When pasting I saw that the typographic quotes were converted to normal ones what breaks the command as now the outer quotes form new pairs and the command doesn't make any sense as the quotes to search for are gone.